# delete sqlite database when updating new version of application

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have uploaded an apk (version 1.0) with 22 tables in **SQLite Database** on Google Playstore.

Now i want to update database with 36 tables in new version (version 2.0) of application.

> I am storing `datebase` at default location so when i press **"Clear
> data"** in **Application Manager**, database is gonna deleted.

I just want to know how to delete old database (same as clear data) when user update new version?

#### Update:

If is there any solution for clear data while updating application from play store then also answered me.

Your help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I think you are using .sql file from assets folder right?

Comment: No, I am creating database at default location of application and use it.

Comment: I mean you are using SqliteOpenhelper?

Comment: Yes, of course. I have created database using `SQLiteOpenHelper`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally done with simple solution:

```
/** UPGRADE DATABASE **/
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    Log.i(TAG, "Database Version: OLD: "+ oldVersion + " = NEW: "+newVersion);

    if(context.deleteDatabase(DATABASE_NAME))
        Log.i(TAG, "Database Deleted....");
    else
        Log.i(TAG, "Database Not Deleted..");
}
```

Comment: Hi @Pratik Butani, where do you add this, in the onCreate method of the first activity the user will see?

Answer (score 8):

you can use this [method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html#deleteDatabase%28java.lang.String%29) to delete your database.

```
context.deleteDatabase(DATABASE_NAME);
```

You can also use this [method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html#getDatabasePath%28java.lang.String%29) to find your database path first and then delete that.

```
File myDb = context.getDatabasePath(DATABSE_NAME);
Boolean isDelete = myDb.delete();
```

The other solution is , if you want to update your database then just change your version number of database. `onUpgrade()` will automatically get called and your old database will be deleted and new database will be created.

Comment: Thanks Waqar, but i want to delete on updation of application so where i can put this code.

Comment: when you are going to update your app let say on update button click. then what you need to do is to call deleteDatabase method and then call your sqlite class object and its method getReadableDatabse() and your new databse will be created.

Comment: `context.deleteDatabase(DATABASE_NAME);` in `onUpgrade()` worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Nice Question. Just follow the steps.

1) There are two methods that you override on Your Helper class

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    if(oldVersion!=newVersion){
        // Remove all old tables and crate new ones
    }
}
```

2) create an object of Helper class.

```
MyOpenHelper dbHelper = new MyOpenHelper(this,"dbname", 1);
```

3) Now just increase the `database version` when you want to change the database.(Third argument in MyOpenHelper class. "1" is a database version).

4) When database version changes it will give you a callback in `onUograde()` method.

5) Remove all tables in `onUpgrade()` method and create new ones.

6) That's it.

**EXPLANATION :**

Your app `version 1.1` is on google play and your `database version is "1"`. Now you want to upload version 1.2 with new database. Just set database version "2" in your helper file. And check the the **oldVersion** and **newVersion** in `onUpgrade()` method if both are not same that means application updating and remove old tables and create new ones.

Comment: No, but i want to `deleteDatabase` at the time of updation of application. How can i know that application is updating. Is there any Event or Receiver?

Comment: check the version condition if old and new are not same upgrade the database

Comment: if i dont want to delete my users local database in my next release what should all i should keep in my mind..can i simple publish my app to 1.1 without changing db version which was 1????

Comment: Yes. If you don't change the version it will not call onUpgrade() method. If you not changing dbversion your previous database will be as it is.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `SQLiteOpenHelper` just delete your tables in your `onUpgrade` method and recreate all your tables again. You should have not problems at all.

Check [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html) out.

Hope it helps

Note: Be careful with database versions, if you are playing with your database numbers make sure you have the right number as your `oldVersion` or it will not work properly when you update your google play.

Comment: This means you have to bump your database version every time you update your app, even if you don't actually update anything and just want the database to be recreated.

Comment: Well you bump your database from version 'A' to version 'B' after that version, you can do whatever you want with it. Just need to be careful with your database values.

Comment: @Philio Yes, you got my point, Is there any receiver that detect updation of application.

Comment: I was a bit sleepy when I wrote that and didn't quite phrase it as I was thinking. This is the correct way to do it, however if you did want to repeat the behaviour on an app upgrade without any changes to the database you would still have to increment the version of the database again. You could perhaps use the context.deleteDatabase() method mentioned in another answer and fire it off in an upgrade receiver as an alternative if you wanted to always delete the database on app upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious solution is to delete the old DB file when onUpgrade() is called and copy the new version over. Too bad it does not work. You get an error something like this:

Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteReadOnlyDatabaseException: attempt to write a readonly database (code 1032)

SQLiteLog﹕ (1032) statement aborts at 4: [PRAGMA user_version = 2]
SQLiteLog﹕ (28) file unlinked while open: /data/data/my.package/databases/my_db.db

You don't need to delete the database, just copy over it using the method you've alady defined (copyDataBase), like this:

```js
@Override  
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {  
    Toast.makeText(myContext, "onUpgrade called!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
    if (oldVersion < newVersion) {  
        Log.v("Database Upgrade", "Database version higher, upgrading");  
        try { 
            copyDataBase(); 
        } catch (IOException e) { 
            throw new Error("Error upgrading database"); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

wrok for me, thank